# Some tips to maintain a Rudraksha and rules to wear it

Tags: rudraksha

As a part of maintaining a Rudraksha , which type of water should be used warm or cold? And can anyone wear a Rudraksha while bathing and sleeping while taking proper care?

Can anyone share the whole details as to how to maintain a Rudraksha from authentic scriptures. Thank you.